# Access WhatsApp logs using R

Tags: r, whatsapp

I know that WhatsApp backs up my chat logs to Google Drive and I can load them back on in case I lose my data locally.
The problem is that this data is usually encrypted hence I can't read it using R.

is there a WhatsApp package that can help me do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need a package for that. Instead of the backup function, you can simply use export to get a txt file with your chat.

In the chat you want to analyse, just hit the three dots menu and navigate to export:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Export either to your phone's storage, Google drive, send the file via mail or however you want to transfer the chat to your computer. You will get a .txt file, which you can read into R:

```
whatsapp_chat <- readLines("WhatsApp.txt")
whatsapp_chat[1:10]
```

You will get your history one message per line.

Comment: Great! is there a way I can export a log of all the chats at once or must do for every one?

Comment: I think it's only possible for one chat at a time.

Comment: BTW if you are intrested, this questions inspired me to start a package for working with WhatsApp data in R: https://github.com/JBGruber/LexisNexisTools

Comment: @JBGruber: That should be [github.com/JBGruber/rwhatsapp](https://github.com/JBGruber/rwhatsapp), I guess?

Comment: @JBGruber: BTW, could you add functionality to send whatsapp messages from R (if that is even possible)?

Comment: That would be awesome! But I don't think it's possible. As far as I understand, whatsapp is end-to-end encrypted and messages are sent from the phone of the sender to the phone of the receiver. Alternative clients or apps are not allowed. The only way I could imagine doing it would be to use a "remote control" for your phone (like http://web.whatsapp.com/) and control that via R. But thats beyond what I can do at the moment.

Comment: The export function in WhatsApp has a limit of 40000 messages, does anyone know how to get the complete history of a chat?